# Bash bracket expansion: How to match all files names with a number?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I want to match all filenames in a directory that are like this:

```
h1.txt, h2.txt, h12.txt, h3.txt
```

If I do

```
echo h[[:digit:]].txt
```

I get

```
h1.txt, h2.txt, h3.txt
```

so it matches all the files I want, except `h12.txt`, because it has two digits instead of one. Is there an expansion for *one or more* digits?

Comment: you could also use `find` command with regex

Comment: Using `find` when there is a simple built-in shell feature is overkill.

Comment: yeah .. thats true .. i just mentioned it when you need more power and filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
echo h+([[:digit:]]).txt
```

Comment: For completeness, this requires the `extglob` option to be set: `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: @chepner How do I know it this option is set in my environment?

Comment: I mean, without running this code and seeing if it works.... is there a way to directly obtain the current option value?

Comment: `shopt -p extglob` will output the current status. If it is set, the output will be `shopt -s extglob`; otherwise, `shopt -u extglob`.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching).