# Globbing: Matching files names with a number in a script?

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I want to match all filenames in a directory that are like this:

```
h1.txt, h2.txt, h12.txt, h3.txt
```

Suppose the directory is `test/`. I have a script called `test.sh` with the following:

```
p=test/h
echo $p+([[:digit:]]).txt
```

but this gives an error:

> ./test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '(' ./test.sh:
>
> line 2: 'echo $p+([[:digit:]]).txt'

Can someone explain what is going here? This works fine in console, please, see [Bash bracket expansion: How to match all files names with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35433926/855050).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to enable `extglob` to make that glob expression work:

```
shopt -s extglob

p='test/h'
echo "$p"+([[:digit:]]).txt
```

**output:**

```
test/h1.txt test/h12.txt test/h2.txt test/h3.txt
```

Comment: It is enabled in my shell.

Comment: Which shell are you using? This does not work for me.

Comment: Oh... it is enabled in the terminal, but not inside scripts. Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: I have GNU bash 4.3.30, it does not work for me, output: `test/h+([[:digit:]]).txt`

Comment: @hek2mgl It works for me `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Sorry, not for me. Looks like a settings thingy. However I'm using a vanilla ubuntu, vanilla bash for the test. I copy/pasted the script from the question. What gives you `shopt | grep glob` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl: do the files `test/h1.txt`, `test/h2.txt` etc. exist? what's the output of `echo test/h*.txt`?

Comment: @becko: also, make sure you use quotes for `"$p"` as shown in this answer (you didn't use them in your question, and it's wrong, in case the expansion `$p` contains spaces or glob characters).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Good catch! Thanks! I'm missed the test folder in my test. The files were in the root folder.. :) However, I would still not use that kind of globbing. `find` is the way to go here (IMHO)... But still +1 and thanks for showing that it is possible!

Comment: @hek2mgl globbing can be great if you want to populate an array as `ary=( test/h+([[:digit:]]) )` or loop on the files as `for file in test/h+([[:digit:]]); do ...; done`. Depends on the task, really.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Sure, it can be great. Especially the fact that word splitting does not happen if you `for f in GLOB` ...

Comment: @becko Just one thing, I think I was confused by the headline: It used the term `bracket expansion`. While there are not `bracket expansions` in bash I assumed `brace expansion`. However, `brace expansion` and `globbing` are two completely different kind of things. I've corrected that.

Comment: @hek2mgl I guess you're right. I don't know where I heard "bracket expansion". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `find`:

```
find test -type f -regex '.*h[0-9]+.txt'
```

---

Original (outdated) answer:

Using a range might work for you:

```
echo test/h{1..99}.txt
```

Comment: That's a way around. But I may not know initially the range of values. I want to match only the numbers that correspond to files.

Comment: If you don't know even the range, how can you know the numbers that correspond to files? Can you tell me what is your basic task (not the desired solution)?

Comment: By looking at the files. That's what bash expansion is supposed to do by itself. Like when you just use `*`, and it automatically expands to the files in the directory. You don't have to know in advance what files are there.

Comment: `find` might be the tool of choice for you then.

Comment: I want to pass this expansion to another command. For example, I want to `cat` the contents of the files. So how can I pass the output of `find` as arguments to another command?

Comment: Use the `exec` option: `find test -type f -regex '.*h[0-9]+.txt' -exec cat {} +`

Comment: Thanks. This may be a better approach, but I have to accept the other answer because it answers the question as I stated it.